# Parse Javascript how to constrain query: "not contained in result of other query's key"

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have `User` class and `Follow` class. `User` is the standard Parse `User` class. My `Follow` class contains the `follower` and `followed` columns, both pointers to `User` instances.

I am trying to return a list of `User`s which are **not** followed by my user. I know I can get the follows first and then locally call `notContainedIn`, but it involves loading the array first locally. I want to execute my query in "one shot" (at least in my code side). This is my current code:

```
var recommendedPeopleQuery = new Parse.Query(User);
[...]
var user = request.user;
var followingsQuery = new Parse.Query("Follow");
followingsQuery.equalTo("follower", user);
recommendedPeopleQuery.???? //it should exclude
                            //followingsQuery's "followed" results.
```

What should the last line be?

Comment: Can you use Cloud Code to chain the queries together in the cloud before returning the dataset to the client?

Comment: @mbm29414 Yes, I can do it using the promise pattern/backbone style completion handlers. But it usually overcomplicates the code and reduces readibility. I'm looking for a cleaner solution that will just give me what I want as a result of query. I know inner queries work in Parse (e.g. `matchesKeyInQuery`) so it should be technically possible to finish in a single query with a subquery.

Comment: I scoured the Parse documentation for a while thinking about this issue, and I am now convinced that Parse has not yet enabled query features to accomplish this in one query. I **did** come up with a Promise-based Cloud Code function to accomplish this that wasn't terribly over-complicated.

Comment: @mbm29414 Sad to see such a feature (which has the technical ground ready) is missing in Parse SDK. Anyway, I'll go with the promise pattern.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, but they **do** continue improving the platform. I'd make a feature request. It's a very reasonable feature to request! ;-)

Comment: @mbm29414 You are right. They are getting better everyday. I'll post it to Google Group.